# If G is a group of order 6, Show that it is ismorphic to S3 or C6

Tags: abstract-algebra

How can i proccess to show that G is isomorphic to S3? espetially i'am blocking in showing that if we don't have a element of order 6, then we must have an element of order 2 and 3.
thank u.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Such a small group can really be taken care of by writing out all possible multiplication tables. There will be precisely two. Alternatively, take $C_2, C_3$ and see what you can do by taking their semidirect product. When doing that, one acts on the other. Check how that affects the whole thing.

Comment: Since the order of elements must divide 6, the non-identity elements must have order 2 or 3. Use this in conjunction with filling in a multiplication table as Nelli Kuukeri suggests.

Comment: Okey i see, i will try the hard way then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well   (and it's "or", not "and"), by Cauchy we have  elements of order $2$ and $3$.  Then since  $2\mid3-1$, you get $C_3\rtimes C_2$, which is $S_3$, or, if the action is trivial,  $C_6$.

---

Allow me to try to argue without Cauchy.
Suppose there are no elements of order three.  But then the group has exponent two, so is abelian. We're essentially done.

Just note that the elements of order  $3$ come in pairs.   By counting we now come up with the element of order  $2$.

Comment: thank u for the correction, english it's not my main language ^^.

Comment: but we don't have to use the cauchy theoreme, sry for not telling this earlier, so how we could proceed?

Comment: also what u mean with 2∣3−1?

Comment: Right you don't need Cauchy.  $2$ divides $3-1$.

Comment: You can use Lagrange and argue...